# How to solve a system of three first-order ODEs in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am using Matlab to try and solve a system of three first-order ODEs, but the error message I get is 'syms' requires Symbolic Math Toolbox.
Error in spiders (line 1)
syms f(t) s(t) v(t) r W c h q a k b H K e

On a previous occasion, I received an error saying that this system of ODEs cannot be solved explicitly (i.e. in closed form). I think that numerical integration is the only way. The r,W,c,h, etc are parameters. Could someone please tell me how I can simulate/solve and plot the ODEs below?

```
syms f(t) s(t) v(t) r W c h q a k b H K e
r = 1;
W = 0.5;
c = 0.4;
h = 0.9;
q = 9;
a = 5;
k = 0.8;
b = 6;
H = 3;
K = 1.3;
e = 2;
ode1 = diff(f) == r*f*(1 - f/W) - c*s*f - h*(1 - q)*f;
ode2 = diff(s) == s*(-a + k*b*v/(H + v) + k*c*f) - h*K*q*s;
ode3 = diff(v) == v*(e - b*s/(H + v)) - h*q*v;
odes=[ode1;ode2;ode3]
S = dsolve(odes)
plot(S);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you where previously using a different MATLAB license, which included the Symbolic Math Toolbox. I assume you no longer have it available and you are now looking for numeric alternatives.

You have to define functions for the equations you are trying to solve. Then you can call one of the ode solvers. An example from the documentation:

```
y0 = [1; 0; 0];
tspan = [0 4*logspace(-6,6)];
M = [1 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 0];
options = odeset('Mass',M,'RelTol',1e-4,'AbsTol',[1e-6 1e-10 1e-6]);
[t,y] = ode15s(@robertsdae,tspan,y0,options);
```

Where `robertsdae` is the equation to solve. The full example including further explanations is [available here.](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/solve-differential-algebraic-equations-daes.html)